# setting schemaLocation for wsdl with jax-ws

Tags: jax-ws

Hye, i am using jax-ws for my webservices. The class for webservice as below

```
@WebService(
    portName = "GuidStatusPort",
    serviceName = "GuidStatusService",
    targetNamespace = "http://url/wsdl",
    endpointInterface = "com.smartap.ws.GuidStatusWs",
    wsdlLocation="https://myurl/guidstatus")
 public class GuidStatus implements GuidStatusWs{
 ...................
```

After deploy, the wsdl file shows schemaLocation as below

```
... namespace="http://smartapws.org/wsdl"    schemaLocation="http://myurl:80/guidstatus?xsd=1" ...
```

How can i set the schemaLocation from my java class?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Java class is not a schema, therefore schemaLocation can not be set to a java class.

Answer (score 0):

as of JAXB v2.1, schema location can be set on XmlSchema annotation usually bound to package in **package-info.java** file

```
@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema(namespace = "http://message", elementFormDefault = javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED, location="http://my/schema/location/Message.xsd")
package my.beans;
```